# Should the rules for the Workplace Stack Exchange be changed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

It seems this site is riddled with moderator closings. 
https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

On the front page, you have to actively look for a question that hasn't been closed or put on hold. Often these questions are genuinely interesting, have many upvotes, and many upvoted answers, and yet are still closed/held for some bureaucratic technical reason that doesn't mean anything to outside observers.

Should the rules for that site be changed so they are more appropriate and tailored to the typical subject matter it attracts, or at least be made more clear so users can write a question there without a greater than 50% chance of it being closed?

Or should there at least be a warning at the top of the site, saying "you're probably wasting your time posting here, because the mods WILL find a reason your question isn't valid"?

To illustrate with an example: [I am slated to be put on performance improvement plan for sixty days, I have one week to decide & I don't know what to do](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/85170/i-am-slated-to-be-put-on-performance-improvement-plan-for-sixty-days-i-have-one)

This is a genuinely educational post as a result of the answers. It is interesting and informative. It is a quality thread that will help other people in the same situation. It is exactly what a "workplace" question and answer thread would be expected to look like. However the mods just pile on by applying their vague rules with strict scrutiny, clamping down on that thread lest it... something.

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked on meta.workplace, instead of the main meta?

Comment: 'closed/held for some bureaucratic technical reason' - you mean 'did not read the rules/policy of the site but posted anyway?

Comment: @dim: OP does not have 5 rep for that ... which I suppose may be somewhat indicative, perhaps, but they deserve *some* chance at an answer.

Comment: Yes Martin that's what I mean, with the fault lying in the rules and moderators and not the user community at large, which is why I suggest the rules be changed rather than the users.

Comment: The moderators _are_ the user community.

Comment: And the user community decide on the rules. The "fault" here seems to be your misunderstanding of how the site is intended to operate. An influx of questions that don't meet the community's expectations does not soften or invalidate those expectations. Many off-topic questions being closed is an indication that the community feel strongly about what they're building, and don't want it diluted down. You'll just have to concede that you've found a place which is not intended for the types of query you want it to be for. The internet's a big place, we don't need every post in the world here

Comment: I think @NathanTuggy gave an excellent job overview of why we have so many closed questions but if you want to discuss the Workplace's question criteria you should do so on our meta site. But I suggest reading the previous discussions about that and familiarising yourself with how SE sites operate first. As mentioned they are not a forum and moderation is in fact largely left up to the community. You refer to the site being "riddled with moderator closings" when that is not my experience. Of the 30 most recently closed questions just 2 obviously off-topic questions were mod closed.

Comment: The Workplace has an explicit close reason for questions asking, "what should I do?" without a clear, stated goal. In fact, it is exactly what that question is doing - asking "what should I do?" without giving a goal and the question was closed for that reason as a result.

Comment: I had posted the same observation on *their* meta couple of years ago, [have a look](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/3037/3192). The difference being that I had focussed more on how we could get the unfit questions out of the way, rather than how to lower the bar to allow them. Also, as others have pointed out, spend some time understanding how the community works. "Moderator closings" occur very rarely, it is the community that closes questions that don't fit the community-made rules. To change the rules, you first need to join the community.

Answer (score 10):

You may find [The Trouble With Popularity](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/) interesting, as it is specifically written about the confusion between what is *popular* and what is *high-quality*. All SE sites are (intended to be) chiefly about the latter.

The Workplace has a bit more of a challenge in this than most sites, as unfortunately most people have lots of opinions about a great many matters of workplace politics that they really do not have any specific expertise in, and love to express those opinions, upvote other posts that agree or are similar, downvote competing opinions, and so on and so forth. This is less quality and more populism, which is precisely the problem the blog is talking about. That is, recommendations tend to be upvoted not because they will be effective in handling problems, but because they sound good to people who know next to nothing about that type of problem and have no stake in it.

So, in short, the rules of the site *have* been tailored to the (in many respects, quite unfortunately challenging) nature of the subject matter. The fact that this results in more moderation, not less, is entirely by design and I cannot imagine there would be much support at SE itself, or among experienced users, for changing this.

(This answer is written as someone quite familiar with SE at large but who rarely goes to TWP except to upvote similar opinions and downvote disagreeing ones, and so tries to go there as seldom as possible.)

Comment: Since the workplace is a political place, and there is no such thing as "high quality" political answer, I submit that this is a place where popularity and factual "high quality" merge.
Also most people do not have experience in workplace politics? Really? I'm pretty sure most people here have held a job. Unless there is a degree called "workplace politician", that makes everyone equally qualified. 
This is one topic where anecdotal reports and opinions are genuine data.

Comment: @Meiji: I disagree strenuously with the idea that there can be no political expertise. It is certainly plausible to argue that everyone affected by a decision should have some say in it, however reasonable or uneducated they may be, but of course voters and answerers on TWP are not going to be affected by the advice they give. They are in the place of campaign managers and political theorists, not constituents.

Comment: I submit that there is a very recent example in the US of the constituents proving wiser than political theorists. An example where one political expert believed in above-90% certainty of their victory, and yet was defeated. Perhaps you can guess that example!
Since politics is people expressing their will to power, the only form of political expertise I guess you can have is just being better at getting power, such as knowledge of political history (which you use to your advantage). I fail to see how anyone can demonstrate this expertise in a forum post, and thus upvotes are good enough.

Comment: @Meiji Lesson #1: The SE network **is not a forum**

Comment: If it quacks like a duck, it's a duck. It's clearly a specialty forum with two-level replies, and ultra-strict rules and moderation on what you can start a thread about.
In this reply he's said the purpose of these strict rules is to improve quality. I submit this is a clear case of it doing the opposite.

Comment: @Meiji: Forums are where you go to *discuss* things. Stack Exchange is where you go to get *answers* **without** discussion. Hence, not a forum. It would be more appropriate to call Facebook a forum than Stack Exchange, but I have never heard anyone do so.